# JSF2 + Primefaces : DataTable lazy loading issue

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I guess, my java code is proper, but records are not showing on dataTable.

Please check below code. i dont know where i made mistake.

**.xhtml**

```
 <p:dataTable value="#{userDetailList.userDataList}" var="user" rows="5" 
                            paginator="true" lazy="true" 
                            paginatorTemplate="{RowsPerPageDropdown} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} 
{CurrentPageReport} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}">

                        <p:column headerText="No">
                            <h:outputText value="#{user.id}"></h:outputText>
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column headerText="User Name">
                            <h:outputText value="#{user.userName}"></h:outputText>
                        </p:column>



                    </p:dataTable>
```

**.java**

```
@PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        // +getter , setter
        userDataList = new LazyDataModel<UserDetail>(){

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public List<UserDetail> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField,
                    SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String, String> filters) {

                return lazyDataModelCom.getResultList(first, pageSize, sortField, sortOrder, filters);
            }
        };
    }
```

**getResultList**

```
public List<UserDetail> getResultList(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String, String> filters) {
        Session session = HibernateUtils.getsession();

        Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(UserDetail.class);
        criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("id"));

        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : filters.entrySet()) {
            if (entry.getValue() != null) {
                criteria.add(Restrictions.ilike("id",
                        "%" + entry.getValue() + "%"));         }
        }

        criteria.setMaxResults(pageSize);
        criteria.setFirstResult(first); 

        return criteria.list(); 
    }
```

**getResultList** method return a proper value, i debug it. 
i think problem is in **userDataList**.

Comment: is UserDataList and your managedBean serializable ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `LazyDataModel` implementation is not setting rowCount. You should do something like:

```
public void init(){
    // +getter , setter
    userDataList = new LazyDataModel<UserDetail>(){

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public List<UserDetail> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField,
                SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String, String> filters) {
            userDataList.setRowCount(...);
            return lazyDataModelCom.getResultList(first, pageSize, sortField, sortOrder, filters);
        }
    };
    userDataList.setRowCount(...);
}
```

Pay attention that `rowCount` is feeded with the number of rows *before* pagination but *after* filtering.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13973903/870122) containing a working example (with the only difference that it uses JPA Criteria API instead of Hibernate Criteria):