# Display lazy loaded datatable's rowCount outside of it

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm trying to display the rowCount of a lazy loaded datatable before displaying the datatable itself.
The problem is that the rowCount value is set in the load callback function so the displayed value is wrong.

Is there a ajax event on datatable component which is triggered when the render or the load of the datatable is done?

Comment: Set rowCount in a bean's method annotated with `@PostConstruct`, just as in the example given here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13973903/870122

Comment: that implies to make a additional sql query...

Comment: No, the additional query is only necessary if you have a very large result set and you need to paginate it