# Can a CDI injected EntityManager from an EJB module be passed around after wiring into JSF CDI bean in web module?

Tags: jakarta-ee, primefaces, ejb-3.0, cdi, entitymanager

I have a web module and an ejb module packaged into an EAR.

I have JSF backing beans successfully injecting Session EJBs from from the ejb module which are able to pull data from the DB, E.g.

```
@RequestScoped
public class CarController {

    @EJB
    private CarService carService;
```

To support Primefaces LazyDataModel, the session EJB exposes it's EntityManager to a LazyDataModel:

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    MyLazyDataModel<Car> myLazyDataModel = new MyLazyDataModel<Car>();
    myLazyDataModel.setEntityManager(carService.getEntityManager());
    super.setMyLazyDataModel(myLazyDataModel);
}
```

This causes the follow exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to retrieve EntityManagerFactory for unitName null
at    com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.init(EntityManagerWrapper.java:132)
at    com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper._getDelegate(EntityManagerWrapper.java:173)
at   com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.getCriteriaBuilder(EntityManagerWrapper.java:895)
at com.cars.web.controller.MyLazyDataModel.load(MyLazyDataModel.java:154)
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable.loadLazyData(DataTable.java:731)
```

Is this not working because the PersistenceContext is only a valid bean to pass around within the ejb module?

Answer (score 0):

For the purpose of resource and / or EJB injection, working with JSF beans or CDI beans is equivalent.

I would avoid retrieving the EntityManager in two different ways (i.e. through PersistenceContext injection and through EntityManagerFactory) inside the same application. In particular the EntityManagerFactory instantiation is a heavyweight operation.

If you make `MyLazyDataModel` an anonymous inner class, it's much easier because you can use the injected DAO service directly, don't need to handle the EntityManager directly in the bean. You can see a concrete example in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13973903/870122).

Unrelated to the concrete problem, the best suited bean scope for a lazy datatable seems to be at least ViewScoped (that is only available for jsf beans).