# Perform query and record count using CriteriaBuilder

Tags: sql, primefaces, criteria-api

I populating a Primefaces datatable lazily with a custom complex dynamic query built using CriteriaBuilder, performing a SQL query on a database.

For that I need to perform a record count using this query and I also need to run the query itself to get the record in the specified interval for the datatable.

So I thought I could do something like this:

```
    CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = this.getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Object> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery();
    Root<RSip> from = criteriaQuery.from(RSip.class);
    Path<Long> eSipss = from.join("idESip").get("ss");
    CriteriaQuery<Object> select = criteriaQuery.select(from);
    List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList();
    //Many predicates added according to user end
    predicates.add(...);
    predicates.add(...);
    predicates.add(...);
    //The query is now ready
    select.where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]));

    //but I need also to perform the record count using SQL Count as the dataset returned can be very large
    CriteriaQuery<Object> selectCount = criteriaQuery.select(criteriaBuilder.count(fromCount));


   //and then perform both selects like this:
   //Record Count:
    TypedQuery<Object> typedQueryCount = this.getEntityManager().createQuery(selectCount);
    List<Object> recordCount = typedQueryCount.getResultList();
   //Query:
    TypedQuery<Object> typedQuery = this.getEntityManager().createQuery(select);
    List<Object> records = typedQuery.getResultList();
```

The problem is that on this second query, it returns me the record count also and not the actual records...what can I be doing wrong?

If there is some other way to do this I'm happy to read your answer!

Comment: just separate the two queries into different methods...
or at least create criteriaQuery object for each one...

Comment: Hava a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13972193/how-to-query-data-for-primefaces-datatable-with-lazy-loading-and-pagination/13973903#13973903