# Primefaces LazyDataModel return empty List

Tags: primefaces, lazydatamodel

I am developing an app to view emails.
The inbox is often very large and I want to use LazyDataModel to extract them by parts.
Data extraction works, but the init() function apparently first renders and then extracts them.

Bean:

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    JwmaSession jession = (JwmaSession) getfromSession("jession");
    listaCorreosEntrada = new LazyCorreoDataModel(jession);
    System.out.println("Rows number: " + listaCorreosEntrada.getRowCount());
}
```

LazyCorreoDataModel:

```
@Override
public List<Correo> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String, Object> filters) {
List<Correo> messageList = new ArrayList<Correo>();
    try {
        Store store = jession.store;
        jFolder = new JwmaFolder(store, "INBOX");
        messageList = jFolder.messageList(false, first, pageSize);
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("List size: " + messageList.size());
    return messageList;
}
```

At the time of executing this code, the result is:

```
Rows number: 0
List size: 10
```

I have not used LazyDataModel much, but I think it should be the other way around.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to query data for Primefaces dataTable using lazy loading and pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13972193/how-to-query-data-for-primefaces-datatable-using-lazy-loading-and-pagination)

Comment: You must invoke `setRowCount` as explained in the accepted answer of the duplicate question

Comment: Many thanks @perissf, indeed missing: `this.setRowCount(messageList.size());`
And implement `@Override getRowKey ()` function.