# Primefaces LazyDataModel: (Outdated)

Tags: java, primefaces, lazy-loading, lazydatamodel

I have a huge list of objects, each of them contains number of images. I want to use lazy loading to fetch them partially. And I want to understand how to use LazyDataModel and how it works.

Initially I thought that I have to **save only ids** of potentially fetched objects inside *LazyDataModel*. And **when load() method invoked - I have to fetch images from DB** and replace *datasource* with fetched data. So every time I want to load more data, I run query.

```
private List<MyEntity> datasource; // contains only ids of MyEntity

@Override
public List<MyEntity> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String,Object> filters) {
    //rowCount
    int dataSize = datasource.size();
    this.setRowCount(dataSize);

    //get listOfIdToFetch

    //paginate
    datasource = datasource.addAll(myJpaRepository.findByIds(listOfIdToFetch));
    return datasource;
}
```

I couldn't make it work because primefaces used lock() method and throwed exception when new portion of data supposed to be loaded:

> org.springframework.webflow.conversation.impl.LockTimeoutException:
>   Unable to acquire conversation lock after 30 seconds

Finally I understood that primefaces example of LazyDataModel (where **the full list of data saved to *datasource*, including all images**), might be the correct way of using. Because initially I thought it is simplified dummy example and in real project I will use sql queries to fetch images part by part.

```
private List<MyEntity> datasource; // contains all images of all records
@Override
public List<MyEntity> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String,Object> filters) {
    //rowCount
    int dataSize = datasource.size();
    this.setRowCount(dataSize);

    //paginate
    return datasource.subList(first, first + pageSize);
}
```

I want to understand how LazyDataModel works and increases performance. If the correct way of using this approach is to retrieve all data from DB and save it to *datasource*. Does Primefaces keep this data on server and flushes part by part? **What if sql result contains thousands of images**, should I look for a different approach and set limit of retrieved records? How to achieve the best lazy loading performance increase? Or maybe the initial approach is correct and I should investigate why this error occurs?

Comment: The whole idea is that you query only the page that you need in `myJpaRepository `, not everything and then take a page from all the results.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Ok, I finally did it and the idea that I should **execute query each time load() method is fired** was correct.

Problems I faces:

1. If I return simply the result of my query - **load() method is fired only once**, and I can't load more data. So i use dummy **sublist(0, chunkSize)**.
2. I **couldn't @Autowire my repository**, I had an exception saying some objects are not Serialized. But I **could use EntityManager** and that's what I did.

Source code:

```
private List<MyEntity> datasource; // contains only ids

@Override
public List<MyEntity> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String,Object> filters) {
        StringBuilder queryText = new StringBuilder("select ...");
        List<MyEntity> list;

        //paginate
        if(datasource.size() > pageSize) {
            try {
                list = new ArrayList<>(datasource.subList(first, first + pageSize));
            }
            catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                list = new ArrayList<>(datasource.subList(first, first + (datasource.size() % pageSize)));
            }
        }
        else {
            list = new ArrayList<>(datasource);
        }

        boolean setComa = false;
        for (MyEntity a: list) {
            if (setComa) {
                queryText.append(","+a.getId());
            } else {
                queryText.append(a.getId());
                setComa = true;
            }
        }
        queryText.append(")");
        Query q = em.createQuery(queryText.toString());
        list = q.getResultList();
        return list.subList(0, list.size());
}
```

UPDATE LIMITING:

```
@Override
public List<MyEntity> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String,Object> filters) {

    List<MyEntity> list;

    Query q = em.createQuery(this.queryText);

    // Paginate
    q.setFirstResult(first); 
    q.setMaxResults(pageSize); 
    list = query.getResultList();

    return list.subList(0,list.size());
}
```

Comment: This is not the way to limit.. please Google "sql limit offset"

Comment: For a correct way of limiting, look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13972193/how-to-query-data-for-primefaces-datatable-using-lazy-loading-and-pagination/13973903#13973903

Comment: This is indeed not the way of solving this. Everyone reading this answer shoud **NOT IMPLEMENT IT LIKE THIS**